# OmniFaces o:validateAllOrNone in ui:repeat or h:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, validation, omnifaces

Is it possible to use OmniFaces `<o:validateAllOrNone>` (which is pretty cool ;)) within an `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`?

I need a table with each row having an input field column. You could either fill in none of these values or all of them.

If I put the `<o:validateAllOrNone>` within the `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` and use the id of the input field in `components` attribute, then the validator also gets triggered, if all fields are empty.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. The `components` attribute must refer physically multiple components, not a single component which is rendered multiple times. It can however be used on physically multiple components which are rendered during same iteration round.  The `<o:validateXxx>` multi field validator is not designed to reference a single component which is rendered multiple times. The only OmniFaces validator which does that is `<o:validateUniqueColumn>`.

If you want to use the `<o:validateXxx>` multi field validator on dynamic inputs based on a collection, then your best bet is to use JSTL `<c:forEach>`. It will build physically multiple components.

E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText id="input_#{loop.index}" value="#{item.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Assuming that there are 3 items, this will dynamically create JSF components with IDs of `input_0`, `input_1` and `input_2`. Then you can just use `<o:validateXxx>` as follows (put it outside the loop!)

```
<o:validateAllOrNone components="input_0 input_1 input_2" />
```

You can replace the hardcoded string in the above example by an EL expression which returns the desired space separated string of component IDs from a backing bean.

```
<o:validateAllOrNone components="#{bean.inputIds}" />
```

An alternative would be to create a `<x:validateAllOrNoneColumn>` yourself or to post an enhancement request at OmniFaces issue tracker. It would be not exactly trivial to alter the existing `<o:validateAllOrNone>` that a completely separate component is desired.

Comment: ah okay, thanks so far, so i think the best way is to use this c:foreach approach...