# Validate if list in <ui:repeat><h:inputText> has at least one non-empty/null value

Tags: list, jsf, validation, uirepeat

I've a `List<String>` in my model:

```
private List<String> list;

// Add to list: "d","e","f","a","u","l","t"
// Getter.
```

I'm presenting it in the view as below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.list[loop.index]}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

This works fine. Now I'd like to validate if the list contains at least one non-empty/null item. How can I create a custom validator for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't easily possible with a custom validator. There's namely physically only one input component whose state changes with every iteration round. Your best bet is to hook on `postValidate` event of `<ui:repeat>` and then visit its children via [`UIComponent#visitTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree%28javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback%29) on the `UIRepeat`.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" varStatus="loop">
    <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.validateOneOrMore}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.list[loop.index]}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

With this `validateOneOrMore()` method (again, just a kickoff example, this approach naively assumes that there's only one `UIInput` component in the repeater):

```
public void validateOneOrMore(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    event.getComponent().visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
            if (target instanceof UIInput) {
                values.add((String) ((UIInput) target).getValue());
            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
        }
    });

    values.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null, ""));

    if (values.isEmpty()) {
        event.getComponent().visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
                if (target instanceof UIInput) {
                    ((UIInput) target).setValid(false);
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });

        context.validationFailed();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Please fill out at least one!"));
    }
}
```

Note that it visits the tree twice; first time to collect the values and second time to mark those inputs invalid.

OmniFaces has an [`<o:validateOneOrMore>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore) component which does a similar thing on fixed components, but it isn't designed for usage in dynamically repeated components.

#### See also:

- [Validate order of items inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469551/validate-order-of-items-inside-uirepeat/)
- [OmniFaces o:validateAllOrNone in ui:repeat or h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776668/omnifaces-ovalidateallornone-in-uirepeat-or-hdatatable/)