# Does postValidate occur during validation phase?

Tags: jsf

```
<f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.action}" />
```

Does the postValidate occur during the validation phase? I tried to use it to do additional validation, but when it failed, the update models phase was still processed. I thought if validation fails it would skip update models.

Comment: How do you 'fail' the validation. Please post code in [mcve] format. In the examples I see is that the renderResponse is explicitly called in a postValidate eventhandler if something fails

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777886/validating-required-on-composite-component-with-multiple-inputs

Answer (score 0):

It occurs in end of validations phase. JSF will only bypass the remaining phases when you explicitly call [`FacesContext#validationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed--).

```
public void postValidate(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
}
```

#### See also:

- [Validate if list in <ui:repeat><h:inputText> has at least one non-empty/null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026625/validate-if-list-in-uirepeathinputtext-has-at-least-one-non-empty-null-val/)
- [Validate order of items inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469551/validate-order-of-items-inside-uirepeat/)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I tried that but it did not work. I'm reposting this in more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777886/validating-required-on-composite-component-with-multiple-inputs